# How do I pass a jQuery function parameter automatically to an outside function?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to pass "term" to an outside function.

```
$('#item').terminal(function(command, term) {
```

The only way I have been able to do this is by passing "term" in the function.

```
myfucntion(term, 'hello world');
```

Is there a way I can do this without having to pass it each time?

**Edit:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#cmd').terminal(function (command, term) {
        switch (command) {
            case 'start':
                cmdtxt(term, 'hello world');
                break;

            default:
                term.echo('');
        }
    }, {
        height: 200,
        prompt: '@MQ: '
    });
});

function cmdtxt(term, t) {
    term.echo(t);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do. Please provide a more complete example.

Comment: I added my full code. As you can see I am passing term into the function outside to be able to call it's echo function.

Answer (score 1):

You could place the declaration of `cmdtxt` inside the anonymous `terminal` callback:

```
$('#cmd').terminal(function (command, term) {

    // ** define cmdtxt using the in-scope `term` **
    function cmdtxt(t) {
        term.echo(t);
    }

    //...

    cmdtxt('hello world');

    //...

    }
}, { height: 200, prompt: '@MQ: ' });
```

By defining the `cmdtxt` function inside the callback function, you place `term` inside the scope of `cmdtxt`. This is because `term` is in-scope at the time of the `cmdtxt` definition, and JavaScript allows a function to have access to all variables that are in-scope at the time of the function's definition. (In computer science terms, we say that in-scope variables are included inside the new [function closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29)'s *lexical scope*.)

Note, however, that this change will make `cmdtxt` inaccessible outside of that callback function. If you do need the `cmdtxt` function elsewhere, you can always redefine it within whatever scope you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make it global to both functions.

```
var my_store = {
   term: // what ever is term probably function(){.....}
};
$(function () {
    $('#cmd').terminal(function (command, term) {
        switch (command) {
            case 'start':
                cmdtxt('hello world');
                break;

            default:
                term.echo('');
        }
    }, {
        height: 200,
        prompt: '@MQ: '
    });
});

function cmdtxt(t) {
    my_store.term.echo(t);
}
```

The reason I put it in `my_store` is for polluting the global space as less as possible. So its role is for storing variables accessed in the global scope.